# Where are the Yoast SEO titles and descriptions stored?

Tags: wordpress, yoast

I'm managing a small directory website and I have set some generic titles and descriptions for my pages with Yoast SEO Plugin.

[image]

I'd like to duplicate them to every entry/page directly via the MySQL database. However, I cannot find it in the DB.

I didn't find it in `wp_postmeta`, `wp_posts` or `wp_yoast_seo_meta`.

That's why I ask: where does Yoast (v. 7.8) store the SEO informations that a user set?

Comment: You might want to ask this on [Wordpress.SE](//wordpress.stackexchange.com), as you're more likely to get an answer

Answer (score 6):

So after some time, I figured out that the best way to find out where this data where stored was to dump the DB and look in that dump:

```
mysqldump -u wordpress --no-create-info --extended-insert=FALSE wordpress -p > dumpydump.sql
cat dumpydump.sql | grep "What you're looking for"
```

What you'll find is an row called `wpseo_taxonomy_meta` in table `wp_options` which contains every taxonomy SEO texts. It is saved as a [PHP serialised value](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.serialize.php).

Be careful though that this is just for the SEO texts of the Taxonomies (e.g. Location, Feature, Category...). It doesn't apply to the SEO descriptions and titles of the posts themselves (these are stored in `wp_postmeta` with at least one row per post).

Answer (score 2):

Yoast SEO Save Description and Keywords  in **wp_yoast_indexable** Table. Where you can see column name description and keywords

Answer (score 1):

You can use this (for categories):

```
$wpseo_options = get_option( 'wpseo_taxonomy_meta');
$wpseo_options['category'][<the_category_id>]['wpseo_title'] = '... my title';
$wpseo_options['category'][<the_category_id>]['wpseo_desc'] = '... my description';
update_option('wpseo_taxonomy_meta', $wpseo_options, true);
```

It should work. Also, you should check the **wp_yoast_indexable** table for correct recordings.

Answer (score 0):

just use this code, you'll get an array of all settings that Yeast SEO show under "Search Appearance" page. Including title, descriptions and all other settings.

```
$wpseo_search =get_option( 'wpseo_titles', $default = false );
```

Update your required field and save using the update_option() function of WordPress.